# How to handle groups of the same html with some dynamic content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have a lot of these html groups.

```
<div class='col-lg-1'>
  <p class='list-group-item-text text-center'>
    <i class='fa fa-icon fa-2x'></i>
  </p>
</div>
<div class='col-lg-10'>
  <h3 class='list-group-item-heading'>
    Action
  </h3>
  <p class='list-group-item-text text-center'>
    About this action.
  </p>
</div>
<div class='col-lg-1'>
  <p class='list-group-item-text'>
    <i class='fa fa-the-same-icon fa-3x'></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

And these usually repeat themselves on a page at least 3 or more times. I was thinking about putting this in either a helper or partial but I'm not sure how I would dynamically change the 3 important pieces of these blocks which are:

```
<i class='fa fa-icon fa-2x'></i>

Action # the <h3>

About this action. # the <p>
```

Whenever I need to. I ideally I would like to make this one line of code. Right now if I do `content_tag` it will be 3 lines of code which makes my views hard to read:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, content_tag(:i, "", class: 'fa fa-icon fa-2x'), class: 'list-group-item-text text-center'), class: "col-lg-1") %>
<%= content_tag(:div, content_tag(:h3, "Action", class: 'list-group-item-heading'), class: "col-lg-10") %>
<%= content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, content_tag(:i, "", class: 'fa fa-angle-right fa-3x'), class: 'list-group-item-text'), class: "col-lg-1") %>
```

How would you handle this so it just one line of code but I can change the icon, header and paragraph content?

**Answer**

This is what I ended up doing:

**shared/_group.html.erb**

I'm using HAML and did this:

```
.col-lg-1
  %p.list-group-item-text.text-center
    %i{class: "fa " + a + " fa-2x"}
.col-lg-10
  %h4.list-group-item-heading= b
  %p.list-group-item-text= c
.col-lg-1
  %p.list-group-item-text
    %i.fa.fa-angle-right.fa-3x
```

Without HAML I think it's something like this:

```
<div class='col-lg-1'>
  <p class='list-group-item-text text-center'>
    <i class='fa <%= a %> fa-2x'></i>
  </p>
</div>
<div class='col-lg-10'>
  <h3 class='list-group-item-heading'>
    <%= b %>
  </h3>
  <p class='list-group-item-text text-center'>
    <%= c %>
  </p>
</div>
<div class='col-lg-1'>
  <p class='list-group-item-text'>
    <i class='fa fa-the-same-icon fa-3x'></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Than on another page like **welcome/index** you can do this:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/group', locals: { a: 'fa-icon', b: 'Action', c: 'This is the Action.' } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if I insult your intelligence, but this is the type of situation where you'd use `variables` with a `loop`.

--

**Partial**

If you want to output your `HTML` groups, you can either use a `partial` or `helper`. I would recommend [`partial`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) because `helpers` are mainly for `Ruby` code (not HTML):

```
#app/views/your_controller/_partial.html.erb
<div class="your">
    html here
</div>
```

The difference is if you use a `partial`, you will be able to [pass `local` variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) to it, giving you the ability to manage the variable data inside:

```
#app/views/your_controller/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "_partial", locals: { x: y } %>
```

--

**Variables**

The important part you need to consider is *how* you will pass the dynamic values to your partial. I think this is the most important part for you.

If your values are made up of static data, you'll be best setting them manually:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def your_controller
   @actions = [{action: "action, value: "value"}, {action: "action", value: "value"}]
end
```

This will allow you to call this in your view, passing it to the `partial` as follows:

```
<%= render partial: "partial", locals: { x: @actions } %>
```

Doing this will pass the variable data to your partial, allowing you to output it using a loop:

```
#app/views/your_view/_partial.html.erb
<% x.each do |action, value| %>
    <%= action %>
    <%= value %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Collection**

A further point to make about this method is to use the [`collection`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) argument in your partial render call:

```
<%= render partial: "partial", collection: @actions %>
```

This will remove the requirement for a loop inside your partial

Answer (score 0):

Partials accept parameters, so if you have those values available just create a partial and pass them into the partial as parameters.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#partials